# Only mock an import if it can't be found in jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

The code base I work on is built by different teams who have access to different proprietary packages.

Normally this is fine, but if I want to make sure my code changes don't break for their builds, I need to build it as them and run the shared tests.

Here's a dummy example:

```js
// in SharedComponent.tsx
import { ChildComponent } from 'variations/foo-bar';

const SharedComponent = () => <><ChildComponent /></>;
```

And the contents of `variations/foo-bar/ChildComponent` vary based on how the code is built (in essence `variations/foo-bar` is replaced by `variations-team-awesome/foo-bar` when built by 'team-awesome' and `variations-team-amazing/foo-bar` when build by 'team-amazing').

Here is an example:

```js
// in variations-team-awesome/foo-bar/ChildComponent.tsx
import { DoThings } from '@proprietary-X/things'

const ChildComponent = () => <div>{DoThings()}</Div>
// in variations-team-amazing/foo-bar/ChildComponent.tsx
import { DoStuff } from '@proprietary-Y/stuff'

const ChildComponent = () => <div>{DoStuff()}</Div>
```

If I build the `SharedComponent` for my jest tests as 'team-awesome' but their version of `ChildComponent` imports something proprietary I don't have access to, then jest will fail saying it can't find the module.

However, if the imports in `ChildComponent` are *always* mocked, then it won't get tested as part of `SharedComponent` (assume it makes sense to not mock them in these examples).

How can I conditionally mock these imports (i.e. `@proprietary-Y/stuff` and `@proprietary-X/things`) for the different teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Forgiveness is easier than permission

In this case, it's better to try and import, and only mock if it fails.

This works in either the test file itself:

```js
// manual mock in a function
jest.mock(
  '@proprietary-X/things',
  () => {
    try {
      return jest.requireActual('@proprietary-X/things');
    } catch {
      console.log('module not found, mocking...');
    }
    return {
      DoThings: () => 'mocked DoThings',
    }
  },
  { virtual: true },
);
```

n.b. virtual is needed when the mock is for a module that doesn't exist (which is won't depending on the team).

Or using `__mocks__` folders (with a helper function):

```js
const conditionallyMock = (module, mock = {}) => {
    try {
      return jest.requireActual(module);
    } catch {
      console.log(`module '${module}' not found, mocking...`);
    }
    return mock;
}

// in __mocks__/@proprietary-X/things
module.exports = conditionallyMock('@proprietary-X/things', {
  DoThings: () => 'mocked DoThings',
});
// in __mocks__/@proprietary-Y/stuff
module.exports = conditionallyMock('@proprietary-Y/stuff', {
  DoStuff: () => 'mocked DoStuff',
});
```

This should work smoothly for both teams, and only console log out `module '${module}' not found, mocking...` when you locally build as the other team and run the shared tests.